# Automatic insertion of checksum guards

Tags: shell, assembly, checksum

As part of my project, I have to insert portions of code(called checksum guards) to protect some function. This process has to be automated i.e. I need to write a script to insert these guards in an assembly. I do have the guard template with me, I am not sure how to proceed.

How do I write a shell script to insert code in the assembly file generated from a source file in C?

**EDIT:**

This is the paper which I am trying to implement.
cerias.purdue.edu/assets/pdf/bibtex_archive/2001-49.pdf
The authors have mentioned that they have modified the binary to insert the guards but that seemed tough. So, I thought of modifying the assembly code.

Here is a guard template:

```
guard:
      add ebp, -checksum
      mov eax, client_addr

for:
      cmp eax, client_end
      jg end
      mov ebx, dword[eax]
      add ebp, ebx
      add eax, 4
      jmp for
end:
```

where client_addr and client_end mark the beginning and ending of the code to protect respectively.

I realize that my understanding of the paper is not complete and I am still unclear about various issues, but I am trying to figure it out.

How do I give the various functions(to protect) as an input to the shellscript?

1. I can give the name of the functions as a string.
2. I can give the starting and ending address of the functions( found using gdb).

But after inserting the checksum guard, the addresses would change so I think giving the name would be a better idea.
Is it so?

I am new to SO, and therefore still need to learn a lot about the correct ways to post a question. 
But Thank you for helping and guiding me.

Comment: If by _checksum guard_ you mean to protect a function from stack overrun exploits, then that's normally referred to as a _stack canary_. There's an implementation example (for C) [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37547/how-to-implement-canaries-to-prevent-buffer-overflows).

Comment: You described a task, you did not ask a question.  You need to go back to whomever gave you this task.  And challenge him, as stated it is the kind of feature that *might* sound reasonable to managerial ears.  It is not.  Asking "what do you mean" is your job, not ours.

Comment: You mean like gcc inserts when you use `-fstack-protector-strong`?  That just writes and reads a sentinel value; it doesn't checksum anything.  What exactly are you checksumming / CRCing / hashing?

Comment: @PeterCordes I am applying checksumming on a portion of code i.e. the instructions. I would be traversing through the function to protect, taking one instruction at a time and storing it(opcode) in a register and applying functions(XOR, ADD, etc.) on it in order to get a value(key). Now if somebody tampers with the code, the value would not be same as the 'key'. Therefore, I would know that it has been tampered with. The thing is I need to take input from the user the functions to protect and then execute the script to insert checksum guards at appropriate places.

Comment: This is the paper I am trying to implement. https://www.cerias.purdue.edu/assets/pdf/bibtex_archive/2001-49.pdf

Comment: @500-InternalServerError No, I am not trying to protect the function from stack overrun exploits but an attacker who can insert, delete or modify instructions in the assembly/binary.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this automatically might be a real challenge, although I rather think it is impossible.

In structured languages it is relatively easy to find out (via parsing and counting curly brackets in C, for example) where a function starts or ends, thus where a function prologue and epilogue should be inserted.

In assembler, this is impossible - A label is not necessarily the start of a function and a "ret" not necessarily the end.

Your best bet would be to build yourself macros for prologue and epilogue and insert them manually.

Some weak hint in your question makes me think the assembler code you are working with could probably be generated from a C compiler - In that case, it might actually be possible by analyzing the emitted asm code whether you can re-construct C function boundaries.

EDIT after some clarifications:

I cannot quite see why this needs to be done in assembler and why it needs to be done to an .asm file produced after compilation - C would just do fine and the pieces of (simple) guard code could simply be injected by a macro (that *could* probably use inline assembly). All in all, if you do it in the original sources, it would be way easier. And, for having asm sources produced by a compiler, you would just as well need access to the C (or whatever) sources.

In another comment you're saying "They are modifying the binary itself and adding guards." - Inserting something *into* a binary is quite a complicated task - you are moving code to higher addresses and need to first find all callers of that piece of code and then adjust addresses. Not even virus programmers do that :) . They replace piece of existing code with jsr instructions to a "backpack" that is placed at the end of the binary. I think the pictures in the linked paper are a bit misleading.

Comment: Yes, the code which is to be protected is a C code. I have made some edits to the question. Could you look at it? I have this doubt as to how do I take the input (to my shell script) of the function to protect?

Comment: I have mentioned the paper which I am trying to implement in the question. They are modifying the binary itself and adding guards. Isn't doing it in assembly easier?

Comment: Can you suggest what kind of obfuscation technique I should use to prevent my guard template from being easily recognizable to an attacker who disassembled the binary?